# Prove that $\|I-S\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1} |((I-S)x,x)|\leq c$.

Tags: operator-theory

Let $S$ a linear, self-adjoint, bounded and positive operator. In a document I'm reading, it says that

> since $0\leq I-S\leq cI$ with $c<1$ then $$\|I-S\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}
>  |((I-S)x,x)|\leq c<1$$

But I can not understand why $\|I-S\|\leq c$.

I apologize if the question can be too trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $0 \leq I - S$ means that $(0x, x) \leq ((I - S)x, x)$ for all $x$. Likewise, $I - S \leq cI$ means that $((I - S)x, x) \leq ((cI)x, x)$ for all $x$. As $(0x, x) = 0$, we see that

$$0 \leq ((I - S)x, x) \leq ((cI)x, x) = (cx, x) = c(x, x) = c\|x\|^2.$$

Taking absolute values, we see that $|((I - S)x, x)| \leq c\|x\|^2$. Therefore

$$\|I - S\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1}|((I - S)x, x)| \leq \sup_{\|x\| = 1}c\|x\|^2 = c.$$

Then as $c < 1$, $\|I - S\| < 1$.